# minicolors won't work in production properly but works in development(Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have install [Jquery-minicolors-rails](https://github.com/kostia/jquery-minicolors-rails) in my Rails application. I am using the following configuration using simple form. I have followed all the steps given in the github readme. I am getting the wheel in the local but not in the production. Any Ideas why? When I saw the console in Chrome it said that the asset(here only..not anywhere else..the picker image is not loading I guess) is not loading. How do I solve this?

```
<%= f.input :body_background,:as=>"minicolors",:class => "minicolor", input_html: {data: {
      minicolors: {control: :wheel}}}%>
<%= f.input :link_hover_color,:as=>"minicolors",:class => "minicolor", input_html: {data: {
      minicolors: {control: :wheel}}}%>
```

I also tried this is in the javascript:

```
$('#white_label_body_background').minicolors({control: 'wheel'});
$('#white_label_link_hover_color').minicolors({control: 'wheel'});
```

Comment: what about assets precompilation before deploying ur app?

Comment: thst is done without any error. All my other assests are loading without any problem

Comment: Are you using Rails 4 and and deploying to heroku?

Comment: No I am not hosting in Heroku. I have my own server. Yes it is Rails 4

Comment: @Aravind did you solve this? I am running into the same problem right now. Thanks!

Comment: Ah never mind found the solution in their Github issue tracker: https://github.com/kostia/jquery-minicolors-rails/issues/8